# R caught segfault address 0xc, cause 'memory not mapped'

Tags: python, r, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to call a function in Python that uses functions in R through `rpy2`, which in turn access the Chemistry Development Kit (CDK), a Java library, through `rcdk`.
The R function takes a string describing a molecule's structure and outputs a numeric object describing its chemical properties:

```
get_descriptors <- function(smiles){
mol <- rcdk::parse.smiles(smiles)
dnames <- rcdk::get.desc.names()
descs <- rcdk::eval.desc(mol, dnames, verbose=FALSE)
return(as.numeric(descs))
}
```

The Python function essentially passes output from the above function into a list. After calling this function, I get:

```
R[write to console]: 
*** caught segfault ***

R[write to console]: address 0xc, cause 'memory not mapped'

R[write to console]: 
Traceback:

R[write to console]:  1: 
R[write to console]: .jcall(desc, "Lorg/openscience/cdk/qsar/DescriptorValue;", "calculate", 
R[write to console]:     a, check = check)
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  2: 
R[write to console]: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  3: 
R[write to console]: tryCatch({
R[write to console]:     .jcall(desc, "Lorg/openscience/cdk/qsar/DescriptorValue;", 
R[write to console]:         "calculate", a, check = check)
R[write to console]: })
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  4: 
R[write to console]: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  5: 
R[write to console]: lapply(molecules, function(a, check) {
R[write to console]:     val <- tryCatch({
R[write to console]:         .jcall(desc, "Lorg/openscience/cdk/qsar/DescriptorValue;", 
R[write to console]:             "calculate", a, check = check)
R[write to console]:     })
R[write to console]: }, check = FALSE)
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  6: 
R[write to console]: rcdk::eval.desc(mol, dnames, verbose = FALSE)
R[write to console]: 

R[write to console]:  7: 
R[write to console]: (function (smiles, type) 
R[write to console]: {
R[write to console]:     mol <- rcdk::parse.smiles(smiles)
R[write to console]:     dnames <- rcdk::get.desc.names()
R[write to console]:     descs <- rcdk::eval.desc(mol, dnames, verbose = FALSE)
R[write to console]:     return(as.numeric(descs))
R[write to console]: })("O=[N+]([O-])c1ccc2ccc3cccc4ccc1c2c34")
R[write to console]:
```

Running the function line by line in R gives the expected outputs with no errors, so I'm not sure the error is a failure to access the CDK, though I may be wrong.

I've checked I have all the necessary dependencies in R and Python installed. I'm using Python 3.8.3 and here's my R session info:

```
version  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
os       macOS Catalina 10.15.3      
system   x86_64, darwin17.0
```

Happy to provide further information if needed.

Comment: "running the function line by line" do you get the error if you run the function with the input you would be sending from python? Here I mean extract your output (for example saving it to a json file or something) and run the function in R and not python.

Comment: Yes, I run each line of the function using the string input from python. But I only check that it produces the right output within R; I haven't tried saving it to an external object.

Comment: What about running the function as a whole (eg. not line by line but `get_descriptors(inputs)`, which i tried to formulate in my question?  What it is saying in the function is basically that there is no variable stored at a specific memory-address in the function. So somewhere your variable is removed at run time. It is not plausible for us to debug this without a reproducible example.